# Great Poker Hand Daniel Negreanu vs Alec Torelli

Tags: betting-strategy, poker-strategy, hand-history

One of my favorite hands

100/200 tournament 6 handed

**pre**

Daniel Negreanu
UTG+1
A♣J♠
raise to $400

Alec Torelli
UTG+2
5♠5⋄
call $400

not going to cover the rest of the action as they all fold on the flop

**flop**

pot $2000

Q⋄5♣2♣

UTG+1
raise $1150

UTG+2
raise $2500

folds

UTG+1
call $2500

**turn**

pot $7000

J♣

UTG+1
raise $3000

UTG+2
call $3000

**river**

pot $13200

A⋄

UTG+1
all in $7075

UTG+2
fold with a set

**General analysis of each player?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preflop:

Standard so far

---

## Flop:

Negranu cbets, Torelli raises for value, Negranu calls only for [floating](http://www.pokerlistings.com/10-more-essential-hold-em-moves-floating-the-flop),  probably thinking that either Torelli is bluffing, or 
has a weak hand likely to fold. Probably lots of history going on here between them. Note that Negranu has no real equity in the hand BUT has the Ace of clubs as a [Blocker](https://www.pokernews.com/pokerterms/blocker.htm)

---

## Turn:

Flush comes and Negranu leads, only representing the nut flush. Torelli normally calls, to cover some of Negranu's bluffs that will shut down in the river and also has the full house as back-up in case Negranu has a flush. Fully justified.

---

## River:

Negranu shoves. Again representing the nuts, top-two pair is irrelevant.
Torrelli believes him for a flush and folds.

---

## Overall:

Quite smart but pretty standard move by Negranu, for these stakes. Given Negranu's general image as shown on TV (not very strong bluffs, especially on the river), it makes sense for most people to fold at this spot. However, we can't further analyse whether Torrelli's reaction was right, since we don't know their history and how Negranu generally played at that specific night.

Comment: Negranu bluffs more than most give him credit for especially late.  Alec said he put in on AA.

Comment: Surely he must be shifting gears in a  tournament, but in general, if you see televised cash games, he plays a quite small-ball strategy, with occasional bluffs in early streets. Surely, Torelli has played with him a lot, so there is history and dynamics we cannot analyse as external observers. Well, AA is a possible hand along with big flushes, that Negranu would have played it like this and value-betted on the river. The real question Torrelli had to answer was whether Negranu value bets (AA,flush,QQ,JJ) or makes a move with rugs. And in the end he leaned towards the first.

Answer (score 0):

will not accept my own answer

**pre**

UTG+1
like the min raise - maybe come in for 2.5 bb

UTG+2
could just call and set mine but I think he wants to isolate on UTG+1 for position

**flop**

UTG+1
not understanding the donk bet
maybe he is repping a big queen wanting to charge a flush draw
he does have the back door nut flush draw
seem like a flush draw would check

UTG+2
set is probably good - charge em

**turn**

UTG+1
seem like repping a made flush

UTG+2
even if he has flush have outs to a boat

**river**

UTG+1
all in - does he think 2 pair is good or is he bluffing a flush
I think it is a bluff
Since he has the ace clubs less likely UTG+2 has a flush

UTG+2
getting 3:1
he only has to be ahead 1:4 to call
UTG+1 is good enough to bluff - AQ, AJ, KQ, QJ with a club
UTG+1 could be on a bigger set or a flush
I think I could call here
Turns out he put UTG+1 on a set of aces which I guess would play this way

Answer (score 0):

Having the whole preflop and flop action is relevant information. The ranges are not the same at all if there were 4 or 5 players seeing the flop rather than just two, even if the  2 or 3 others folded. It makes a huge difference, especially if these other players were in position, which is likely. It requires a much stronger range to lead on flop with 4 players to talk behind instead of just 1, and it affects the ranges for all the rest of the hand, even after 3 of them folded.
 And I'm too lazy to go search for that hand on youtube :)

Also, Paparazzi, your comment on preflop and flop action seems to say Torelli has 3 bet preflop? But the hand as you posted it, he just called preflop.

Finally I have a very hard time thinking dneg is turning top 2 into a bluff here. Possible but I would tend to think he's underestimating Torelli's range and value betting a bit thin, while Torelli does the contrary and hero folds.
 Although if it was indeed a 3 bet pot, and multiway, it does change a lot of things.. hard to discuss a hand with incomplete infos.